# Mongodb change ObjectID or _id attribute for a document?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

How can I change an objects id? It doesn't seem to be just a regular attribute, so I'm not sure if I'm able to update that value?

I'm using Ruby with Mongoid, but I can't figure out how using just the ruby driver, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

MongoDB won't let you update the `_id` field of a document, but you can delete the document and reinsert it with a new `_id` value.

Answer (score 9):

So when you create the items; you can specify your own ID; however you can't change it once it's been created as it's a unique identifier for the row.

A bit more on the [Object Id](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs)

If you want to specify them when creating your items you can do: {_id: 'YourUniqueID'} which will override it.  More information in that above link.

Hope this helps!